# Javascript doesnt work without syntax error

Tags: javascript

This is JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Choose() {
    var n1, Price, Stock;
    n1 = document.getElementById("product").value;
    if (n1 == "1")
      Price = 12.5;
    Stock = 15;
    else
      Price = "40";
    Stock = "5";

    document.getElementById("price") = Price;
    document.getElementById("stock") = Stock;
  }

< /script
```

In the body of HTML:

```
<select id="product"><option value="1" >PRODUCT 1</option>
<option value="2">PRODUCT 2</option> </select
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Choose()">
<input type="text" value="0" id="price">
<input type="text" value="0" id="stock">
```

I need help!Why this code doesn't work?

Where is my failure?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: you're setting elements equal to numbers

Comment: That `script` tag at end is it a typo or ...?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  That includes explaining what the problem is.  Saying "HELP! THIS DOESN'T WORK!" is not explaining the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the value of the DOM element

```
document.getElementById("price").value = Price;
document.getElementById("stock").value = Stock;
```

You need to set the attribute `value` of the DOM element and not the DOM element itself to an integer value

Also you are missing `{}` around the if-else block. I am assuming that you missing the `>` operator while closing the script tag is a typo and not in the original code. If its there change it in the original code too

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Choose() {
    var n1, Price, Stock;
    n1 = document.getElementById("product").value;
    if (n1 == "1") {
      Price = 12.5;
      Stock = 15;
    }
    else {
      Price = "40";
     Stock = "5";
    }
    document.getElementById("price").value = Price;
    document.getElementById("stock").value = Stock;
  }

< /script>
```

```js
 function Choose() {
     var n1, Price, Stock;
     n1 = document.getElementById("product").value;
     if (n1 == "1") {
         Price = "12.5";
         Stock = "15";
     } else {
         Price = "40";
         Stock = "5";
     }
     document.getElementById("price").value = Price;
     document.getElementById("stock").value = Stock;
 }
```

```html
<select id="product">
   <option value="1" >Product1</option>
   <option value="2">Product2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="Choose()">
<input type="text" id="price"/>
<input type="text" id="stock"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I've noticed!

Comment: Also doesnt Work!
<script type="text/javascript">
      function Choose(){
     n1=document.getElementById("product").value;
 if (n1=="1"){
   Price="12.5";
      Stock="15";}
  else {
   Price="40";
      Stock="5";}
document.getElementById("price")=Price;
document.getElementById("stock")=Stock; }
</script>
Main body
<select id="product"><option value="1" >Product1</option><option value="2">Product2</option></select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Choose()">
<input type="text" value="0" id="price">
<input type="text" value="0" id="stock">

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing

Comment: In the body of the Html doesnt return the values

Comment: I have 42 values in the product option is this maybe a problem?

Comment: No you just need to handle them diffrently. Tell me what is the type of elements with id=price and stock, are they input or div etc

Comment: I find the failure.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Choose(){
    var n1,Price,Stock ;
    n1 = document.getElementById("product").value;
    if (n1 == "1") {
      Price = 12.5;
      Stock = 15;
    } 
    else { 
      // place it in block
      Price = "40";
      Stock = "5";
    } // place it in block    

    document.getElementById("price").value = Price;
    document.getElementById("stock").value = Stock;
  }    
</script>
```

Assume that the error you get is misplaced else.
If more than one statements are written under condition or loop, it must be made as block

Comment: you fixed the value issue but didn't say anything about it

Comment: document.getElementById("price").value=Price;
use the property after getting the HTML object then only you can set value to it.
document.getElementById() return an object and value is a property in that object.
Are you clear now?

Comment: i know i'm just saying you didn't mention it as a problem in your answer

Comment: sorry for the delay bro and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it might not be the case but you are missing the end tag of the script.

```
</script>
```

Secondly you are also missing the brackets for the if and else statements.

```
            if (n1=="1"){
                  Price=12.5;
                  Stock=15;
            }
             else{
                  Price="40";
                  Stock="5";
             }
```

Hope it helps!

Br, 
José Sousa